# Point cloud on an STL surface, integrate per element

Tags: paraview

I have a cloud of points that lie randomly on a 3D object surface. The object is a CAD model, can be saved as STL. The point cloud is obtained from ray tracing, each point representing the power of light absorbed when a ray partially reflects off the surface. I would like to visualize **absorbed intensity** on the object, using ParaView.

So, **input**: [x, y, z, p] + STL. (x, y, z) are guaranteed to lie on the object surface, but are likely slightly off the STL due to it being an approximation of the real surface.

**Desired output:** colored STL image, with each surface element coloured according to the total absorbed power in that element divided by its area.

**Optional:** Ideally, the data should be smoothened, something like "sliding average" or Gaussian blur.

**Difficulty:** The main problem I am facing, independent of using ParaView, is that I don't know the intensity, only the power. I can calculate the intensity myself, e.g. in Matlab, and get a poor Matlab graphics (compared to Paraview) and a very noisy image (because of random fluctuation of intensity between pixels due to finite number of rays). ParaView seems to be doing magic, hope to solve this problem with it.

Can I do the above with ParaView, without programming a new filter / with minimum programming?

I have just discovered ParaView, so please excuse a very novice question. Googling for answer didn't help, hopefully I didn't miss it due to poor wording.

Answer (score 1):

**RessampleToDataset** filter should let you ressample your point cloud unto the stl.